# Flutter firebase authentication login success no matter if the user is in the database

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, firebase-authentication

If I try to fill TextFormFields responsible for email and password and submit, the login procedure gonna be success always.. no matter if user is in firebase authentication field. I've done login and register pages before with firebase working perfectly. Only diffrence was using pushNamed instead pushReplace. Should it do difference?

That's form inkwell onTap :

```
onTap: () {
                                      final formState = _formkey.currentState;
                                      if (formState.validate()) {
                                        formState.save();

                                        signIn(_email, _password).whenComplete(
                                            () => Navigator.of(context)
                                                    .pushReplacement(
                                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                                  builder: (context) =>
                                                      HomePage(),
                                                )));
                                      }
                                    }
```

and authentication:

```
FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
Future<void> signIn(String _email, String _password) async {
  try {
    UserCredential user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: _email, password: _password);
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    print('error');
  }
}
```

Email/password sign-in method is turn on.
How to fix this problem and allow to log in only users that exist in firebase?

Comment: ```whenComplete()``` method defines ```The [action] function is called when this future completes, whether it does so with a value or with an error.``` so even its succesful or error login this will always be called

Comment: There's a lot of example on firebaseAuth user checking. Like check if the user exist or null after that then navigate() to somewhere